# SSAS : Week number order by issue

Tags: sql-server, ssas, mdx, ssas-2008

I m running on this weird problem with my cube

```
      Week No
      1  10  11 2   3  4  5  6  7  8  9  
India
Nepal
```

I want to be appear by order (asecending)

My Week no is a string datatype. I tried converting to int. Still the issue is not resolve.

Any inputs would be great.

Thanks !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each attribute in the dimension has following properties that defines how attribute is ordered:

- Order By
- Order By Attribute

Order by attribute is drop down list that contains following options:

- Key
- Name (default option)
- Attribute Key
- Attribute Name

Option `Key` means that attribute will be ordered based on key value. **Do not forget that ordering depends on key type**:

example if key is integer, then ordering will be 1, 2, 3..., 11, 12.

If Key is string, then ordering will be 1, 11, 12, 2, 3 ...

Option `Name` means that attribute will be ordered based on name value.

Option `Attribute Key` means that ordering will be based on attribute that is specified in property "Order by Attribute" key value.

Option `Attribute Name` means that ordering will be based on attribute that is specified in property "Order by Attribute" name value.

Property `Order By Attribute` lets you choose attribute for "Attribute Key" and "Attribute Name" options in "Order By" property.

Hope it help.

To get more info: [How in Analysis Services do you order dimension attribute during design](http://www.ssas-info.com/analysis-services-faq/28-design/89-how-do-you-order-dimension-attribute)